# CS0117: 'TestClass' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentPage'

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

But it does! And it was working yesterday. And **not a single thing in my code has changed.**

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestClass
/// </summary>
public class TestClass
{
    public static string CurrentPage = String.Empty;

    public class Request
    {
        public static void PageName()
        {

            CurrentPage = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Page.cshtml:

```
@{
}

<div id="subHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <p><span>Viewing:</span> @TestClass.CurrentPage</p>
    </div>
</div>
<main id="main" role="main">
```

I have no idea what the heck is wrong. Why is VS suddenly complaining of something it's been letting me do for oh I dunno... 1 year?!

Comment: does it complain about `CurrentPage = Path.Get` in .cs or about `@TestClass.CurrentPage` in cshtml? Have you updated nugets or visualstudio recently?

Comment: Try Rebuild All for starters. Are you saying not a single thing changed *that ought to matter*... Or literally, you diff the files and all the zeroes and ones are the same? P.S. This is why you make backups.

Comment: I would even go so far as to go into all of your projects in the solution and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders manually. Then do a `Clean Solution` and `Build Solution`. I have seen VS do some wonky things.

Comment: I did do a Rebuild All. That didn't fix it up though. And @EdPlunkett yes, I mean literally, not a single thing has changed. And I'm not talking about those files alone, I'm talking about the entire project, not a single file or any part of it has changed.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl No, it doesn't complain about `= Path.Get`, and if it did, it shouldn't, because it was working yesterday, and the day before, and weeks before that - and in other projects, months ago.

Comment: Is `TestClass` in a separate project from `Page.cshtml`? If it is, ensure that the reference to the project/library containing `TestClass` has no problems. View the reference in `Object Browser` to ensure it looks correct and contains all of the members it should, specifically the `CurrentPage` field.

Comment: @gmi It's in the same project. I did however manage to get it working thanks to your previous comment. Deleting the bin folder manually then rebuilding has solved the oroblem

Comment: I will add it as an answer then. Glad it fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that both `bin` and `obj` folders under each project within the solution are cleaned. You can do that by manually deleting them from each project. Once they are gone you can try performing a `Clean Solution` and then a `Build Solution`.